# Export data from DataGrid to MS Word file

Tags: c#, ms-word, wpfdatagrid, export-to-word

maybe someone know how export data from WPF DataGrid control to Word file? Every single example which I found in Internet is about DataGridView (ASP.NET). Havent any idead how can i do that. I have DataSet or whole DataGrid.
Thank you for some help.

Comment: Maybe you can go via an an html Word doc, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019517/c-sharp-httpcontext-does-not-work-when-trying-to-save-html-to-word-in-c-sharp?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Word uses unicode based coding scheme which can not be access by another program. It can only be access by Word itself. But still you can put your DataGrid data to basic .txt file because it uses ASCII based coding scheme which also allows another program to be access.

Accoring to my view use streams to write your DataGrid data to text file and then use it.